# Passing input tensor size to via tensorflow pipeline

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am getting the following error

ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined.     Found `None`.

when passing a tensor using the tf.data pipeline to tf.layers.dense. The relevant parts of my code are:

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    features = {'X': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
                'Y': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32)}
    parsed_features = tf.parse_example(example_proto, features)
    X = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features['X'])
    Y = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features['Y'])
    return X, Y

dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(fin)
dataset = dataset.batch(100)
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.cache()
dataset = dataset.repeat()
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
X, Y = iterator.get_next()

hidden_0 = tf.layers.dense(X, N_HIDDEN_0, activation=tf.nn.crelu, use_bias=False)
```

Is this because passing the tensor shape to tf.layers.dense is not possible with the VarLenFeature or the sparse_tensor_to_dense operation? Is there a way to fix it without using sess.run(X,Y) and feeding the output using feed_dict?

Am wondering if this is similar to the issue that @mrry addressed in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13348.

Any insights would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to fix the problem by changing my def _parse_function to the following:

```
def _parse_function(example_proto):
    features = {'X': tf.FixedLenFeature([18],tf.float32), 'Y': tf.FixedLenFeature([3],tf.float32)}
    parsef = tf.parse_example(example_proto, features)
    return parsef['X'], parsef['Y']
```

So I guess the problem was because with tf.VarLenFeature in my original code, the number of input and output nodes could not be communicated to tf.layers.dense. I am still unclear as to why I have to specify the number of columns of X and Y ([18] and [3] in the code above), instead of specifying them as [ ] - but I can live with that.